# Allocate memory for a pointer to an array in C

Tags: c

I have a pointer array defined declared as

```
char (*c)[20]
```

When allocating memory using malloc

```
c=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

or

```
c=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

I get a warning as "Suspicious pointer conversion"

Why?

Comment: Why would you be using malloc there? `c` is already initialized because it is an array.

Comment: If you just want a pointer to 20 `char`s, chances are you just want `char *c=malloc(20);`.

Comment: no, using size of (c) gets the pointer size

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: No, `c` is just a pointer, and uninitialized.

Comment: @Alex K. Please try to avoid small typo edits and fix the whole post. I lost my changes and had to redo them. That could have saved everybody some work.

Comment: I agree with @JerryCoffin. What is the functionality you want here? Do you want an array of 20 characters, or an array of 20 strings?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I don't see the warning even with warning levels set rather high on GCC 4.6.1 or MSVC 10.

Comment: array of 20 chars, using Borland

Comment: if `c=malloc(sizeof(char)*20)` gives you a warning, you are maybe compiling with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Since you want an array of `char*`, you should use `calloc(20, sizeof(char*))`.  Also, I don't get a warning when compiling this even with `sizeof(char)` (all warnings enabled).

Comment: @Gandaro: who says the questioner wants an array of `char*`?

Comment: @SteveJessop The code+his comment.

Comment: @Gandar: no, `char (*c)[20]` declares a pointer to an array (the array has size 20 and element type `char`), not an array of pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this declaration

`char (*c)[20];`

`c` object has type `char (*)[20]`.

We know that in C `malloc` return type is `void *` and that there is an implicit conversion between `void *` to any object pointer types.

So `c = malloc(whatever_integer_expression)` is valid in C. If you get a warning, you are probably using a C++ compiler or you are using a C compiler but forgot to include the `stdlib.h` standard header.

But `c = (char*) malloc(whatever_integer_expression)` is not valid C because there is no implicit conversion between `char *` type and `char (*)[20]` type. The compiler has to (at least) warn.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have `stdlib.h` included.

Secondly, try rewriting it as

```
c = malloc(sizeof *c);
```

I suspect you're getting the diagnostic on the second case because `char *` and `char (*)[20]` are not compatible types.  Don't know why the first case would complain (at compile-time, anyway) unless you don't have `stdlib.h` included.

**edit**

Remember that you will have to dereference the pointer before applying the subscript; that is, your expressions will have to be

```
(*c)[i] = val;
printf("%c", (*c)[j]);
```

etc.

Alternately you could write `c[0][i]` in place of `(*c)[i]`, but that's probably *more* confusing if `c` isn't supposed to act like a 2-d array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are defining C as a pointer to a static array of chars, not as a pointer to an array of chars, that is, a pointer to the first char.

Change

```
char (*c)[20];
```

for

```
char * c;
```

a

Comment: No, `c` is defined as a pointer to an array of 20 `char`. Array of pointers to `char` would be without the parens.

Answer (score 0):

For an array of 20 characters, counting the NUL terminator, you don't need a pointer

```
char array[20];
```

for a pointer to char, you don't need an array

```
char *pointer;
```

A pointer to char can point to an array

```
pointer = array;
```

to part of the array (assuming no 'funny' business with the NUL terminator)

```
pointer = &array[10];
```

or to a bunch of bytes allocated with malloc

```
pointer = malloc(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use as

```
c=(char(*)[20])malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

Reason:

1, as @ouah said.

2, in K&R style compiler, the above one is valid and expected.